# How do I tell if arcpy is installed?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have a user that recently received a new machine with a fresh install of 10.2. We have a python / arcpy application that worked in 10.1 on the old machine but does not work on the new machine with 10.2. The error message is "ImportError: No module named arcpy".

How do I determine if arcpy is installed on the machine? If it is installed, could  this be a problem with the version?

Comment: generally, for a quick module check, I just type idle in the start menu search bar and then try `import arcpy` when idle opens.

Comment: @mr.adam Keep in mind, IDLE is a separate installation itself.

Comment: well, it's a separate program, but doesn't it always come packaged with python on windows?

Comment: This question sounds more like "how come arcpy is broken, or doesn't work?",  not "is it installed?"

Comment: @KHibma unless Python and Arcpy are automatically installed with every install and it is impossible to unstall or prevent this from happening, I don't think we can assume it is installed. Once I verify it is installed, I may be asking why it's broken.

Answer (score 2):

One way to tell if arcpy is installed is to go into `Add/Remove Programs`, select `ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop`, and click the `Uninstall/Change`.

When the ESRI window opens, select Modify and then click Next, and on the following screen Python should not have a red X on it. If it does have a red X, then you can change it to install the feature.

---

Another way to tell if arcpy is installed is to go into the following directory:

```
C:\Python27
```

And there should be an ArcGIS10.2 folder. Go into that folder and open the python.exe and type `import arcpy`

If it imports fine, then most likely your Environment Variables are messed up. You need to make sure the following paths are listed at the front of the Path variable:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib;
```

Otherwise, a different Python version may be acting as the default.

---

Also, there should be a file in:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages
```

Called `desktop10.2.pth` that simply contains the following text:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts
```